# springboot with spring-data-jdbc and postgres: Trailing junk on timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, spring-data-jdbc

After an upgrade of spring boot 2.2.11 to 2.3.9, some database queries in our application stopped working. When I downgraded to 2.3.8, they did work again.
So something must have changed from 2.3.8 to 2.3.9, but I still haven't found out what it is.

We use spring-data-jdbc and a postgres database. Our repositories extend CrudRepository:

`public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Example, Long>`

and the queries that have issues look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM example WHERE updated_at > :lastUpdate")
List<Example> findByUpdatedAtGreaterThan(@Param("lastUpdate") OffsetDateTime lastUpdate);
```

The entities all extend a class BaseEntity, that has a field
`private Timestamp updatedAt;`

The database column was set up with a flyway script:
`updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()`

This timestamp is set automatically on BeforeSaveEvent:

`this.updatedAt = Timestamp.from(Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)));`

The controller method expects a request parameter

`@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) OffsetDateTime lastUpdate`

and receives something like `2011-01-01T10:20:30.123Z`
which is passed to a service and the repository method.

Now in `org.postgresql.jdbc.TimestampUtils` (postgrsql-42.2.18-sources.jar) I see the parameter `lastUpdate` in a method

`public synchronized @PolyNull Timestamp toTimestamp(@Nullable Calendar cal, @PolyNull String s)`

and then `private ParsedTimestamp parseBackendTimestamp(String str)`

parseBackendTimestamp() seems to expect a timestamp with a space between date and time, not a 'T', and so we get to the line

```
throw new NumberFormatException("Trailing junk on timestamp: '" + new String(s, start, slen - start) + "'");
```

Result: "Trailing junk on timestamp: 'T10:20:30.123Z'"

I don't know why the parameter is passed into parseBackendTimestamp(). With spring boot 2.3.8 this doesn't happen, postgresql version is the same, 42.2.18.
The [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.3.9.RELEASE) for 2.3.9 mention an upgrade to Spring Data Neumann-SR7, which brings
Spring Data JDBC 2.0.7. The [change log for 2.0.7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/releases/tag/2.0.7.RELEASE) is very short, just one bugfix that seems to be unrelated.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Could you create an issue with spring-data-jdbc including a reproducer using Testcontainers? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues

Comment: I'll try, on the weekend.

Comment: Created issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/935